# Having an issue with fread and fwrite function

Tags: c, struct, fwrite, fread

I'm having a problem.

I'm trying to create a file and then reading it again, saving the values in a new structure. But when I try to print the values I just get garbaje after 7 values.

What am I doing wrong?

Or maybe there is a fwrite limit

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct estructura_salida
{
    int num_art;
    int exist;
};

int main (void)
{
    fflush(stdin);

    int i,j;
    long reg;

    struct estructura_salida listado[100];
    struct estructura_salida ventas[100];

    struct estructura_salida listadol[100];
    struct estructura_salida ventasl[100];

    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        listado[i].num_art = i+1;
        listado[i].exist = i+20;    
        ventas[i].num_art = i+1;
        ventas[i].exist = i+10; 
    }

    printf("\ncargados\n");

    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        printf("\n%i\t%i\t%i",listado[i].num_art,listado[i].exist,ventas[i].exist);
    }   

    FILE *fp1;  
    FILE *fp2;  
    fp1 = fopen("C://stock.dbf","wt");  
    fp2 = fopen("C://ventas.dbf","wt"); 


    fwrite(listado,sizeof(struct estructura_salida),200,fp1);
    fwrite(ventas,sizeof(struct estructura_salida),200,fp2);

    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);


    printf("\nleyendo el archivo");

    fp1 = fopen("C://stock.dbf","rt");  
    fp2 = fopen("C://ventas.dbf","rt");     

    while(!feof(fp1))
    {
        fread(listadol,sizeof(listadol),1,fp1); 
    }

    while(!feof(fp2))
    {
        fread(ventasl,sizeof(ventasl),1,fp2);   
    }

    fclose(fp1);    
    fclose(fp2);

    printf("\narchivo leido\n");

    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        printf("\n%i\t%i\t%i",listadol[i].num_art,listadol[i].exist,ventasl[i].exist);
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

this is how the console looks, I just get garbaje.
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZVQ1.png)

Thank you!!

Comment: First issue you have is `fflush(stdin);`.

Comment: Beware of the semantics of [Using `fflush(stdin)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/).  It isn't very portable.

Comment: Also, [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Diagnosis

I believe you are almost certainly working on a Windows system because you used `"wt"` in the `fopen()` mode. The `t` is not recognized by the C standard or most Unix systems.  And also because you [used `fflush(stdin)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/) which is essentially meaningless on non-Windows systems but is defined to do a more or less useful task on Windows systems.

Your primary problem is that you use `"wt"` to open a text file for writing, but when you use `fwrite()`, you are writing binary data to a text file.  That means that entries containing 10 or 13 are likely to cause chaos.

Use `"wb"` (and `"rb"` when reading).  This is supported by the C standard and indicates that you are doing binary I/O, not text I/O, and prevents the I/O system from wreaking havoc on your data.

You are also writing 200 records when you only have arrays containing 100 records (as pointed out by [R Sahu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/434551/r-sahu) in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51794178/15168)) — this is not a recipe for happiness, either.

Your loops using `while (!feof(fp1))` are wrong; using [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong).  You keep reading over the same elements — `listadol[0]` and `ventasl[0]`, because you simply pass the array name to `fread()`.  You could read all the records back in one `fread()` operation per file, or you need to index the array correctly (passing `&listadol[i]` for example).

Strictly, you should verify that the `fopen()` calls (in particular) are successful.  Arguably, you should do the same for the `fread()` and `fwrite()` calls.  The ultra-fanatic would check the `fclose()` calls. If the data file is crucial, you should do that, just in case there wasn't enough space on disk, or something else goes radically wrong.

#### Prescription

Putting the changes together, and using `NUM_ENTRIES` to identify the number of entries (and changing it from 100 to 10 for compactness of output), I get:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct estructura_salida
{
    int num_art;
    int exist;
};

enum { NUM_ENTRIES = 10 };

int main(void)
{
    struct estructura_salida listado[NUM_ENTRIES];
    struct estructura_salida ventas[NUM_ENTRIES];

    struct estructura_salida listadol[NUM_ENTRIES];
    struct estructura_salida ventasl[NUM_ENTRIES];

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ENTRIES; i++)
    {
        listado[i].num_art = i + 1;
        listado[i].exist = i + 20;
        ventas[i].num_art = i + 1;
        ventas[i].exist = i + 10;
    }

    printf("\ncargados\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ENTRIES; i++)
    {
        printf("%i\t%i\t%i\n", listado[i].num_art, listado[i].exist, ventas[i].exist);
    }

    const char name1[] = "stock.dbf";
    const char name2[] = "ventas.dbf";
    FILE *fp1 = fopen(name1, "wb");
    FILE *fp2 = fopen(name2, "wb");
    if (fp1 == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s for reading\n", name1);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (fp2 == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s for reading\n", name2);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fwrite(listado, sizeof(struct estructura_salida), NUM_ENTRIES, fp1);
    fwrite(ventas, sizeof(struct estructura_salida), NUM_ENTRIES, fp2);

    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);

    printf("\nleyendo el archivo");

    fp1 = fopen(name1, "rb");
    fp2 = fopen(name2, "rb");
    if (fp1 == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s for reading\n", name1);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (fp2 == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s for reading\n", name2);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int n;
    for (n = 0; fread(&listadol[n], sizeof(listadol[n]), 1, fp1) == 1; n++)
        ;

    int m;
    for (m = 0; fread(&ventasl[m], sizeof(ventasl[m]), 1, fp2) == 1; m++)
        ;

    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);

    printf("\narchivo leido\n");
    if (n != m)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Read different numbers of records (%d from %s, %d from %s)\n",
                n, name1, m, name2);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%i\t%i\t%i\n", listadol[i].num_art, listadol[i].exist, ventasl[i].exist);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It would be better to use a function to open the files which checks for failure and reports the error and exits — an exercise for the reader.

The output from that is:

```
cargados
1   20  10
2   21  11
3   22  12
4   23  13
5   24  14
6   25  15
7   26  16
8   27  17
9   28  18
10  29  19

leyendo el archivo
archivo leido
1   20  10
2   21  11
3   22  12
4   23  13
5   24  14
6   25  15
7   26  16
8   27  17
9   28  18
10  29  19
```

A hex dump program shows that the two data files contain what you'd expect:

```
stock.dbf:
0x0000: 01 00 00 00 14 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 15 00 00 00   ................
0x0010: 03 00 00 00 16 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 17 00 00 00   ................
0x0020: 05 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 19 00 00 00   ................
0x0030: 07 00 00 00 1A 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 1B 00 00 00   ................
0x0040: 09 00 00 00 1C 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 1D 00 00 00   ................
0x0050:
ventas.dbf:
0x0000: 01 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 0B 00 00 00   ................
0x0010: 03 00 00 00 0C 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 0D 00 00 00   ................
0x0020: 05 00 00 00 0E 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 0F 00 00 00   ................
0x0030: 07 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 11 00 00 00   ................
0x0040: 09 00 00 00 12 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 13 00 00 00   ................
0x0050:
```

There aren't any printable characters except the odd CR or LF in that, so the information on the right isn't all that informative.  (Tested on a Mac running macOS 10.13.6 High Sierra, using GCC 8.2.0.)

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem 1

```
fwrite(listado,sizeof(struct estructura_salida),200,fp1);
fwrite(ventas,sizeof(struct estructura_salida),200,fp2);
```

You are trying to write 200 objects while you have only 100. That causes undefined behavior.

#### Problem 2

Use of `while(!feof(fp1))` is not right. See [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Change the code to read the data to:

```
   int n = fread(listadol, sizeof(listadol[0]), 100, fp1); 
   // Now you can be sure that n objects were successfully read.
```

#### Problem 3

When using `fread`/`fwrite`, open the files in binary mode, not text mode.

```
fp1 = fopen("C://stock.dbf", "wb");  
fp2 = fopen("C://ventas.dbf", "wb");
```

and

```
fp1 = fopen("C://stock.dbf", "rb");  
fp2 = fopen("C://ventas.dbf", "rb");
```